# How to render more than X elements in react? (Performance)

Tags: html, reactjs, loops

I have a huge component that can receive a start and end date, plus some floors numbers, and based on these numbers, it generates a table, something like the below image.

Example of this table:

[image: Example of this table]

The problem is, how to make this table generate faster?

To generate the floors I use a for a loop.

JavaScript code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < section.floorQuantity; i++) {
   floors.push(i + 1)
}
```

and for each day, I generate a column with the number of floors as cells (divs).

Comment: `useMemo` hook might be applicable for your table view https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Answer (score 0):

you can use "useMemo" to cache the same computation and it's result change when input data changes

```
const computeExpensiveValue=(inputs)=>{ 
 //do something 
   return result
  }
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b]);
```